# How to add different Child layout in Co ordinator Layout other than RecyclerView and NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

Is it possible to add `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout` as a children of Co-ordinator layout.

This my layout file I want to add Co-ordinator Layout to it but  unfortunately I have other child Layout which I guess  I can't add in as a part of co-ordinator layout.

Officially I need to add `ScrollView` and then add all those Linear Layout as a child of it but I guess It would be a bad practice to add `RecyclerView` into `ScrollView`.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:theme="@style/Wifi_AppTheme"
android:visibility="visible">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/send_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_file_upload_white_24dp"
    app:elevation="12dp"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/open_gallery"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/send_image"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send_image"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/send_image"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_collections"
    app:elevation="12dp"
    app:fabSize="mini"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/file_transfer_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/status_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/andro"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wifi_device_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/device_status"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/wifi_device_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/disconnect"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_cancel_white_48dp"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you want those LinearLayouts to be at the bottom of your `RecyclerView` and only visible when you scroll all the way to the bottom?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I want thanks for the help @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can add. Coordinator layout is just like any other layout. Just add a layout inside coordinator layout. It can be anything like linear,relative etc, and under it you can put in what ever views you want.